# Restrict users behavior by rows of entity

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I am using Sonata Admin Bundle

It can restrict users behavior like editing or viewing by Roles or ACL.

This privilege is depending on each tables.

However, I want to controll users availability by each rows.

**[For example]**

I have table/entity like this.

```
Id |User  | data
1  |bear  | sarmon
2  |dog   | meat
3  |monkey| banana
4  |bear  | peanuts
5  |dog   | corn
```

Row 2 and 4 data is belonging to user `bear`.

So I want to let user `bear` view and edit only row 2 and 4.

In the screen for bear, listview should look like

```
Id |User  | data
1  |bear  | sarmon
4  |bear  | peanuts
```

This kind of things seems not to be controlled by Roles or ACL

**[My Guess]**

At first, I am struggling with `public function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)`
however I couldn't make it.

So I guess I need to put this kind of code somewhere else checking each rows.

```
if ($row->getUser() == 'bear'){
array_push($lists,$row);
}
else {
}
```

However where? and Am I walking to the right direction???

Is there anyone who use SonataAdminBundle like this??

I guess this situation is not rare case.

For example, in multiple blog management system.

Each user should have the privilege to edit his/her own posts.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Comment: This sounds like a case for the Security Voters.